# JQuery: Mover the Focus to the First Link

Tags: jquery, netbeans-8

How can I move the focus to the first link on the page when the page is loaded using jquery.

Hele is my code:

```js
var url, title;
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("a").each(function() {
        url = $(this).attr("href");
        title = $(this).attr("title");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
            
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    title = $(this).attr("title");
    
    $("#caption").text(title);
    $("img").attr('src', url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you really want. If you want to give focus to the first anchor `<a>` of a page:

```
 $('a').first().focus();
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v24jpaoe/

Comment: Yes that it. But where do I put it? does it go in the $(document).ready(function () field or  $(document).on('click', 'a', function() field?

Comment: @Jabateh Is not very clear from your question. I suggest you try put the code in different places until you are happy with the result :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in many ways. Here's arguably most efficient way. The :first pseudo-class works on any element type or class. (*ie: .button:first, .div:first, li:first*). You can really call this at any time, assuming the links are in the DOM. Here's an [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xonos/k6k9sq4r/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a:first').focus();
});
```

Looking at your comment on the other answer, I believe understanding the order in which javascript executes would be helpful for you. Javascript executes in the order in-which it arrives. Here's an example of HTML + Jquery that will not work as intended.

```
<script>
    $('p').hide();
</script>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

The reason why this will not work is because at the time of execution, the 



 element does not yet exist and therefore, it cannot be hidden. The following correction, will work however.

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<script>
    $('p').hide();
</script>
```

It works because, you guessed it - the order of execution is valid. Now note that Jquery provides a work-around for this. $(document).ready (or) $(document).on. There's other ways as well but these are the easiest. Now there's a reason why you should specifically choose one or the either. Using **.on** is for dynamic content. In other-words, $(X).click / $(X).ready will only work if the content was always there. So, for instance, if you were to do the following:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('body').append('<button>Testing!</button>');
```

The example above will work, because .click is only meant to be executed if the elements already exists. (The same applies to .ready/.load, etc) If the elements ARE on the page already when the script runs, it will work fine.

With this being said, here's a working example of dynamic content being triggered with **.on**.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('body').append('<button>Testing!</button>');
```

> Note: Again, as a disclaimer - I should note that there are ways to
>   force .ready/click/etc to pick up newly added elements to the DOM
>   however, why waste time doing that when there are jquery alternatives
>   built-in? Anyways, I hope atleast some of this helps.